# getting the count of snapshot elements

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to rank my users based on a value, to do that i'm trying to iterate through the list after ordering by a value called "earned_points", however i'm getting the error message `dataSnapshot.numChildren is not a function`.

Here is what my code looks like

```
return rankref.orderBy("earned_points").limit(10).get().then(function(dataSnapshot) {
      let i = 0;
      console.log(dataSnapshot)
      dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const r = dataSnapshot.numChildren() - i;
        console.log(childSnapshot)
        updates.push(childSnapshot.ref.update({rank: r}));
        leaderboard[childSnapshot.key] = Object.assign(childSnapshot.val(), {rank: r});
        i++;
      });

      updates.push(leaderboardRef.set(leaderboard));
      return Promise.all(updates);
```

This should add a rank to every child snapshot and then create a new node called leaderboard.

Any idea to why i'm getting this? i just switched from realtime database to firestore and don't know what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i just switched from realtime database to firestore and don't know what's going on

In firestore, there is no `DataSnapshot`, firestore uses the concepts of collections and documents.

The method `numChildren()` is inside class [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#numChildren).

The [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method is inside the class `CollectionReference` and it returns a `QuerySnapshot`, thus you get an the error `dataSnapshot.numChildren is not a function`

Example of retrieve all documents in a collection:

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
   });
});
```

Check this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data